# Memory Leak in Swift?

Tags: swift

when i check my app with Instruments ill found a Leak - Called

Leaked Object Malloc 64 Bytes, no Responsable Library or Frame - only that simple Entry. This is after i included a Class to my MainTableViewController

Ive stripped out everything useless from my class and tried it again - but i receive the Same Leak.

This is my Class i want to Add:

```
class Questions {

    var questions: [Question] = []

    init() {

        for item in 1...8 {

            var newQuestion = Question(qIndex: 1, qText: "sadas", qTemplate: "dsasd", qHidden: false, qRowHeight: 44.00)
            questions.append(newQuestion)
        }

    }

    func getQuestions() -> NSArray {

        return questions

    }

}

class Question: NSObject {

var qIndex: Int
var qText : String
var qTemplate : String
var qHidden : Bool
var qRowHeight : CGFloat


init(qIndex: Int, qText: String, qTemplate: String, qHidden: Bool, qRowHeight: CGFloat) {

    self.qIndex = qIndex
    self.qText = qText
    self.qTemplate = qTemplate
    self.qHidden = qHidden
    self.qRowHeight = qRowHeight

}

}
```

Anyone got a idea whats the problem here? Thanks in Advance.